# My cat licked a bit of garlic sauce, what should I do?

Tags: cats

My cat had about five or so licks off of a small carrot that was part of a garlic pasta dish. My cat is around three months old and weighs over 3.5 pounds. I’m not sure about her current weight but that’s what the vet said maybe two and a half weeks ago. The pasta brand is the picture. [image] Please help, I’m really worried! Noting that the carrot she licked was half the size of the ones in the picture.

Comment: I don't think a few licks is enough to do harm, but I would monitor your cat, and call your vet for advice.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: **Don't panic!**

It's true that garlic is poisonous to cats, but as with everything, the dosage makes the poison. If the cat licked a carrot that was lightly coated in a sauce that contains *some* garlic, the total amount of ingested garlic is probably extremely small.

The common signs of poisoning in cats, according to [vetinfo](https://www.vetinfo.com/cat-poisoning-symptoms.html) are:

> 1. Lethargy
> 2. Agitation
> 3. Excessive Drooling
> 4. Vomiting
> 5. Lack of Balance or Coordination
> 6. Diarrhea
> 7. Rapid and Superficial Breathing
> 8. Seizures
> 9. Coma

If your cat doesn't show any signs of poisoning, there's nothing you need to do. Just make sure she doesn't come into contact with any more poisonous substances and she'll be okay.

If she does show any of the above mentioned symptoms, call your vet immediately and follow their instructions.